# Cross-referencing equations with fleqn - faulty references in article class

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, alignment

I am currently experiencing issues with cross-referencing my equations while using the fleqn environment with the amsmath and nccmath package. I want my equations to left aligned, hence the use of fleqn environment. However, I noticed that when I try to cross-reference the equation, it seems to be cross referencing the section number and not the equation. Not sure why this is the case.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

Yup Yup

\section{Booyah} \label{sec: booyah}

Find Equation \ref{Eq:GGS_distribution_function_2} below Equation \ref{Eq:GGS_distribution_function} in section \ref{sec: booyah}.

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
R_F(d_p) = \left(\frac{d_p}{d_{p,max}}\right)^m 
\label{Eq:GGS_distribution_function}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
R_F(d_p) = 5
\label{Eq:GGS_distribution_function_2}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Cross-referencing in your document example works just fine. No any issues! The package `nccmath˛is an extension od `amsmath` package, which add to it some new features. So it is sufficient to load only `nccmath`. That all equation start at lef ptext border, you not need to use `fleq` environments locally, just add it as option to document class option or as option to `nccmath˛.

Comment: @Zarko I agree nccmath is not needed for this example but in tl2022 I _do_ see the issue reported, with incorrect `\ref`, which looks like a package bug to me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, . I'm not familiar with TL2022. I use MiKTEX recent version. Using it I didn't observe reported issues. Good to know.

Comment: time to ping Ulrike, our secret spy in both camps...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it breaks in miktex too.

Comment: I thought you'd say that :-) (@Zarko)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you know who to blame https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/652

Answer (score 1):

you could drop nccmath:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

Yup Yup

\section{Booyah} \label{sec: booyah}

Find Equation \ref{Eq:GGS_distribution_function_2} below Equation \ref{Eq:GGS_distribution_function} in section \ref{sec: booyah}.


\begin{equation}
R_F(d_p) = \left(\frac{d_p}{d_{p,max}}\right)^m
\label{Eq:GGS_distribution_function}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R_F(d_p) = 5
\label{Eq:GGS_distribution_function_2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why it breaks is a change in amsmath in 2021
(https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/652):

> \changes{v2.17k}{2021/08/24}{Move the counter inside the equation and guard with a mathopen for better compability with hyperref, issue gh/652} As with hyperref incrementing the counter creates a box to raise the anchor it should be in a place where is doesn't affect spacing.Currently the code from hyperref is used to avoid this problem: If fleqn isn't active the counter is set inside the equation and the potential box guarded by a mathopen to avoid side effects on following unary symbols. If fleqn is activated it has to be outside to avoid problems with labels. This solution is temporary and not necessarly the best.}

So equation is defined differently depending on if the package option `fleqn`  has been set or not. But as `nccmath` set `\@fleqntrue` only locally it doesn't use the correct definition and so breaks.

Comment: `$max$` :(......

Comment: @DavidCarlisle details :-)

Comment: Thanks alot! Really appreciate. Just out of curiosity, do you know why the cross-referencing gave issues?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661163/cross-referencing-equations-with-fleqn-faulty-references-in-article-class?noredirect=1#comment1644810_661163

Comment: @Michael I added a comment.

Comment: I have installed `amsmath` v2.17n, 2022/04/08. How it influence on `nccmath` (which is very old) on OP problems? So far using `\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,nccmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` as start of your answer gives me the very same result as is goten with your MWE.

Comment: @Zarko the question doesn't have `fleqn` as class options.